# Using Cinder Libraries in .dll

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, clr, cinder

I have a C++ project running cinder. I would like to implement a plugin system using LoadLibrary and a .dll file using a custom interface. I got a simple example working, but once I add the cinder libraries to use as a reference in my dll, the dll won't compile, giving an error the  and  are not compatible with compiling with /clr.

I am a greenhorn when it comes to C++, most of my programming is done in C#. Is there anything I could do about this?

P.S. Switching off /clr gives me a bunch of errors about MT_static and MT_Dynamic mismatches in cinder.lib. I'm going nuts here.

Thank you for your help,
Matija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was not all that forward, but after a LOT of trial and error, this finally worked:

I turned off all clr options (set them to no support in visual studio). The the setting for Dynamic Debug DLL needed to be changed to Dynamic no debug (no DLL). After that, it was just a matter of commenting out Stdafx.h and setting and current setting incompatible flags to compatible.

The project built into a normal .dll and is now working fine :D